# cordova: facebook login error" misconfigured for facebook login" in android 4.1

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I have a problem when I run my  android phonegap application with fb integrated on device 
I tested l'app, and I got error when I wanted to login: " is misconfigured for facebook login.... "
My problèm appears just when app facebook is installed in android 4.1 ; when app facebook is not installed, everything works well. but when i run my app in android 2.3.6 even though facebook app is installed everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem if the key hash you entered in your App Dashboard settings does not match the signature you have. This only shows up if authentication is done against Facebook for Android app.

Go check out the troubleshooting section: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#troubleshooting

It discusses how to handle this.